# Splitting string line by line

Tags: string, codeigniter

I am getting an error message like this. How can I split this string line by line. like 'Error Number: 1146' as a string and next line as another string.

```
Error Number: 1146
Table 'baycliff.booking1' doesn't exist
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO booking1 (name, address, phonenumber, email, Noperson, room_id, fromDate, toDate, comment, booking_date, tariff) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '', '', '')
```

Comment: message states that a table `booking1` is not found on your `baycliff` database. . what is your problem?

Comment: ok. How can I split this string line by line because I need the error number and description to be stored in database

Comment: how about `mysql_error()` holds the message and `mysql_errno()` holds the number check it out

Comment: `mysql_` functions are deprecated, so should be avoided.

Comment: Ah I see, are you writing an `error_handler`?